# SQL Server 2008 full-text search doesn't find word in words?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

In the database I have a field with a .mht file. I want to use FTS to search in this document. I got this working, but I'm not satisfied with the result. For example (sorry it's in dutch, but I think you get my point) I will use 2 words: zieken and ziekenhuis. As you can see, the phrase 'zieken' is in the word 'ziekenhuis'.

When I search on 'ziekenhuis' I get about 20 results. When I search on 'zieken' I get 7 results. How is this possible? I mean, why doesn't the FTS resturn the minimal results which I get from 'ziekenhuis'?

Here's the query I use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    d.DocID 'Id', 
    d.Titel,
    (SELECT afbeeldinglokatie FROM tbl_Afbeelding WHERE soort = 'beleid') as Pic, 
    'belDoc' as DocType 
FROM docs d
JOIN kpl_Document_Lokatie dl ON d.DocID = dl.DocID
JOIN HandboekLokaties hb ON dl.LokatieID = hb.LokatieID
WHERE hb.InstellingID = @instellingId
    AND (
          FREETEXT(d.Doel, @searchstring)
          OR FREETEXT(d.Toepassingsgebied, @searchstring)
          OR FREETEXT(d.HtmlDocument, @searchstring)
          OR FREETEXT (d.extraTabblad, @searchstring)
          )
    AND d.StatusID NOT IN( 1, 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you look at using the [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) predicate, as opposed to FREETEXT

Usage scenarios, including what you wish to achieve, can be found in the examples section of the documentation.

From your description, I believe that you are attempting to perform a "Prefix" search. For example:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT Name
FROM Production.Product
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, ' "SearchTerm*" ');
GO
```

This will provide you a result set containing all words that "contain" the prefix search term.

Comment: The asterisk before the search term is not supported by SQL Server.